# How to replace specific words from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I am trying to do some replacement in python strings, I have data like
`The lyrics is not that bad!` and I want to replace that `not that bad` with `good`. Here's the few example of data that I have:

```
I HAVE THIS  --  WANT TO CONVERT LIKE THIS
The lyrics is not that bad!  --  The lyrics is good!
Food is not bad.  --  Food is good.
!! not !! bad !!  --  !! good !!
notbad  --  good
The song is not extremely gently bad for my ears.  --  The song is good for my ears.
The sight is not very very bad.  -- The sight is good.
```

I am trying to write some generalize script that will work for all of them. I am really new in python, and I have tried `str.replace()`, find `str.find()` and then replace. But didn't succeed.

Comment: `str.replace`??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So I want it to work for different sentences. Like:- The input is 'The lyrics is not that bad!' and the output is 'The lyrics is good!' and input - The sight is not very very bad. output - The sight is good. How can I make it into one program?........I have tried str.replace and I have also tried str.find then replace, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string=input("Enter string")
#Input from user is :
string="The lyrics is not that bad!"
string=string.replace("not that bad","good")
print(string)
# The lyrics is good!
```

Here we are asking user to input string, user input `The lyrics is not that bad!` now we have to replace `not that bad` to `good` by `string.replace("not that bad","good")`.
**Edit :**
If you want to generalize then, I found some pattern in your string. Like you want to replace the text between "not" and "bad" with "good". So, you can try this:

```
import re

string=input("Enter string")

#Input from user is :
string="The sight is not very very bad."
string="Food is not bad."
string="The song is not extremely gently bad for my ears."

string=re.sub("not(.*?)bad","good",string)

print(string)
# The sight is good.
# Food is good.
# The song is good for my ears.
```

Comment: It will work for this example....but not for other examples like:- 
input - The sight is not very very bad.
output - The sight is good.
That's why I want to generalise it.

Comment: You have to tell that in question! Okay! I will edit my answer to make that also.

Comment: @SohamSharma does last edit answers your question?

Comment: I am really bad at this! Please excuse me! So these are the results I need:- 
inp = '''The lyrics is not that bad!'''
out = '''The lyrics is good!'''
inp = '''Food is not bad.'''
out = '''Food is good.'''
inp = '''!! not !! bad !!'''
out = '''!! good !!'''
inp = '''*notbad*'''
out = '''*good*'''
inp = '''The song is not extremely gently bad for my ears.'''
out = '''The song is good for my ears.'''
inp = '''The sight is not very very bad.'''
out = '''The sight is good.'''

The code should work for these conditions.

Comment: I had already told you that, don't ignore any messages, we are not your personal code writer. We are here to help you, with your issue. :(

Comment: @SohamSharma sorry for being rude but I have asked you to edit your question and with details but you aren't trying to ignore that. But anyway I have edited the answer. It should work for your all provided data. Happy coding :). If it solves your problem don't forget to mark this as accepted answer. And additionally I am going to edit your question with detail that you provided in comment, just approve that edit.

Comment: Your [efforts in helping the OP to ask better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298829/how-to-improve-a-low-quality-question-with-no-answer-where-the-op-answered-in) are practiced "leading-by-example". I saw your edit, adding  all of OP's clarifying comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To create a more robust solution you need to design like a bot but for your current problem i can suggest a bit of generalize solution. Have a look at example below.

```
# have a list of common terms you want to replace
terms = ["not that bad", "not very bad", "not very very bad"]

# take a user input sentence
str1=input("Enter sentence - ")

# iterate on terms and check if term is present in sentence, if there replace and break
for term in terms:
    if term in str1:
        reverse = str1.replace(term, "good")
        break

# print replaced string
print(reverse)
```

Comment: these are the results I need:- inp = '''The lyrics is not that bad!''' out = '''The lyrics is good!''' inp = '''Food is not bad.''' out = '''Food is good.''' inp = '''!! not !! bad !!''' out = '''!! good !!''' inp = '''notbad''' out = '''good''' inp = '''The song is not extremely gently bad for my ears.''' out = '''The song is good for my ears.''' inp = '''The sight is not very very bad.''' out = '''The sight is good.''' The code should work for these conditions.  Like I want to genralise it for any condition.

Answer (score 0):

To generalise something there needs to be a clear pattern. All your inputs are way too different to filter them out generally.
I'd use a dictionary with the following structure:

```
input_correction = {"not that bad": "good",
                    "not bad": "good",
                    "not very very bad": "good"}

for key, replace_str in input_correction.items():
    if key in inp:
        inp.replace(key, replace_str)
```

Just cover every case in your dict and your good to go.